# Next js + Stripe Environment variable in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, vercel

I have a problem with the environment variable in nextJs and stripe, the problem doesn't accrue in localhost env, but when I deployed to vercel and create a checkout session I got this error

```
Invalid value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string. You specified: undefined.
```

in local everything works great, but in vercel I can't make it to work, I will share my setup for the stripe in next js

next.config.js

```
env: {
 stripe_public_key: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
},
};
```

.env.local

```
# Stripe
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=publickey here 
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=secretKey here
```

vercel env variable witch is the same for local keys

[image]

things I tried :

- add NEXT_LOCAL prefix to the key
  I have the latest next version , so I hope you could help me with this

Comment: Since Next.js 9.4 you don't need any extra setup in `next.config.js` to load environment variables - see [Loading Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables). You should be able to access env vars directly in your code, e.g. `process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY`.

Comment: same error ,  that not  changing anything , it is something weird with Vercel

Comment: Can you show us your code where the error comes from?

Comment: the error is not in the code in local everything si working great, the problem is when I'm in remote I can make a checkout session, the error say i don't have a valid API key , even i put in the environment setting of vercel